# When crudRepository save method return proxy and when normal object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have problem with `CrudRepository`:

1. When i use save method for example `crudrepository.save(proxy Object)` where proxy object is NEW ENTITY it retruns normal object.
2. When i try `crudRepository.save(proxy Object)` where proxy object is EXISTING ENTITY then it returns proxy object

Comment: And the problem with that is?

Comment: what is the problem then?